# How to configure Sidekiq as a service on SUSE SLES15?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, suse

It's now time to deploy my RoR 5.2.4 application to the validation environment. Inspired by [this post](https://przbadu.medium.com/running-sidekiq-as-systemd-process-759ee3fbddd4) and some other readings, I try to setup Sidekiq as a service on SLES15. Here is the service file:

```
#
# This file tells systemd how to run Sidekiq as a 24/7 long-running daemon.
#
# Unit file is created into /etc/systemd/system/ for execution on SLES15@BFS
# The Unit file drives only one instance of the process. To run multiple processes,
# create multiple Unit files and register multiple services
#
# Register and control service:
#   - systemctl enable sidekiq
#   - systemctl {start,stop,restart} sidekiq
#   - journalctl -u sidekiq -rn 100 (shows the last 100 lines of log output)
[Unit]
# Start the service only once the network and logging subsystems are available,
# consider adding redis-server.service if Redis is local and systemd-managed.
Description=sidekiq
After=syslog.target network.target redis-server.service

[Service]
# Sidekiq automatically supports systemd's `Type=notify` and watchdog service monitoring.
# If your Sidekiq process locks up, systemd's watchdog will restart it within seconds.
Type=notify
WatchdogSec=10
WorkingDirectory=/home/a80838986/sis-portal
# If you use rbenv:
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'exec /home/a80838986/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec sidekiq -e validation -C /home/a80838986/sis-portal/config/sidekiq.yml'
# Use `systemctl kill -s TSTP sidekiq` to quiet the Sidekiq process

# !!! Change this to your deploy user account !!!
User=a80838986
Group=linuxusers
UMask=0002

# Greatly reduce Ruby memory fragmentation and heap usage
Environment=MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2

# if we crash, restart
RestartSec=1
Restart=on-failure

# output goes to /var/log/syslog (Ubuntu) or /var/log/messages (CentOS)
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
# This will default to "bundler" if we don't specify it
SyslogIdentifier=sidekiq

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But this way, Sidekiq issues an error:

```
LOGIN[117401]:  ORIGINUSER= PPID=1
sidekiq[117376]: bundler: command not found: sis-portal/sidekiq
sidekiq[117376]: Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
systemd[1]: sidekiq.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127
```

Never the less, ExecStart's statement executes correctly when ran from the application folder `/home/a80838986/sis-portal`.

How to configure this service so that Sidekiq actually works?

Comment: i think ExecStart is not the issue here. are you using capistrano for this? do you have a log of the error.

Comment: I do it all manually at the moment. I'll edit the question to show log's message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, the ExecStat statement did not find the path to *bundle*. I updated it giving the path with the -r option:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'exec /home/a80838986/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec sidekiq 
    -e validation 
    -C /home/a80838986/sis-portal/config/sidekiq.yml 
    -r /home/a80838986/sis-portal'
```

Sidekiq is now up and running, showing a green *Active* status on the console.

Comment: Can you tell me what this Group=linuxusers means here? I mean did u create a group and  add the user to the group just for this template of sidekiq wants us to do so?

Comment: The linuxusers group was created by the service who manages our servers. It lists the users who are allowed to do something on the computer. It is not specific to Sidekiq. But Sidekiq requires that you specify a group the user account belongs.